# Add bitmap/jpg to fixed location in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, stamp

I need to put an image (bitmap or jpg) in a fixed location at the bottom of the last page of an existing pdf.
I've been looking into iTextSharp, but couldn't find if this was actually possible.

Has anyone ever tried this with iTextSharp or another library?

Comment: For extending the search (if not already done so), the keywords "stamp" or "watermark" may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed a topic that is not widely spread or viewed.